# How can I get a specific control within a datagrid at run time?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a `DataGrid` with an `ItemTemplate` in it that is simply just a `<asp:RadioButton>`. Attached is a `CheckedChanged` event.

While debugging in the `CheckedChanged` event I was looking at the `UniqueID` property of `sender`. No matter which row in the grid I click on, I always get this value `dgCodes$ctl12$rbSelect`.

I opened up the dynamic aspx file in my solution to look at the actual contents of the grid, and all of the radio buttons are uniquely numbered as I'd expect;

First Row:

`id="dgCodes_ctl04_rbSelect"`, `name="dgCodes$ctl04$rbSelect"`

Second Row:

`id="dgICDCodes_ctl05_rbSelect"`, `name="dgICDCodes$ctl05$rbSelect"`

---

Again, regardless of which row's radio button I select in my code behind I always get ctl12 (even if there aren't 12 rows in the grid):

```
Protected Sub rbSelect_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim rb As RadioButton = DirectCast(sender, RadioButton)

    Dim uid As String = rb.UniqueID.Replace("$", "_")
    Dim rbSender As RadioButton = DirectCast(dgICDCodes.FindControl(uid), RadioButton)

    ' do stuff with rbSender

End Sub
```

Manipulating `rb` doesn't behave as I need it to, hoping this will allow me to do what I need to.

Answer (score 0):

Well I came up with the most ghetto, non-scalable solution. It works but it's far from good.

Added an `ItemDataBound` event to the Grid which looks for the particular control in question and forces its checked state there.

```
Protected Sub dgICDCodes_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs) Handles dgICDCodes.ItemDataBound

    Dim rb As RadioButton = e.Item.FindControl("rbSelect")

    If rb IsNot Nothing And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(mStrCode) Then
        If rb.Text = mStrCode Then
            rb.Checked = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The more rows in the grid the slower it runs. With 70K records in the grid, it hung for maybe 2 or 3 seconds- but that's not using any search parameters to populate the grid what so ever.

So, again, it works, but not well.